# "textTransform" is not a valid style property even though it says it is in a document?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am styling in React Native and encountered this message saying I cannot use "textTransform" because it is not a valid property.

[image]

However in the React Native documentations, it is part of style props unless I am reading it wrong. Could anyone explain this?[image][image]